# JavaFX How to fix multiple cubes in MeshView?

Tags: java, javafx, 3d, mesh, uicolor

I am adding 16 cubes as a `TriangleMesh` to a `MeshView`. Somehow the cube faces look broken, even though I followed the counter clockwise rules. Maybe having more than one cube in the 3D mesh makes the cubes look broken?
My cube code are two classes in a larger program:
class `Cubes` and
class `Chart3DItem`

```java
import common.Common;
import entities.Location;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.paint.PhongMaterial;
import javafx.scene.shape.DrawMode;
import javafx.scene.shape.MeshView;
import javafx.scene.shape.TriangleMesh;

public class Cubes extends TriangleMesh
{   
   public Cubes ()
   {
      float size = 50;
      
      //    /Z
      //   /
      //  /
      // 0 -------->X
      // |
      // |
      // | 
      // Y
 
      int count = Common.getCurrentGame()
            .getVisitedSolarsystemsMap().keySet().size();
      
      float[] allCorners = new float[count*24];
      int index = 0;
      
      for (Location location : Common.getCurrentGame()
            .getVisitedSolarsystemsMap().keySet())
      {
         float deltaX = location.getX().floatValue()*120; // factor is to scale the range [0 to 10} to [0 to 600]
         float deltaY = location.getY().floatValue()*120;
         float deltaZ = location.getZ().floatValue()*120;
         
         float[] corners = new float[]{ 
               // X, Y, Z 
               deltaX,deltaY,deltaZ+size,
               deltaX+size,deltaY,deltaZ+size,
               deltaX,deltaY+size,deltaZ+size,
               deltaX+size,deltaY+size,deltaZ+size,
               deltaX,deltaY,deltaZ,
               deltaX-size,deltaY,deltaZ,
               deltaX,deltaY+size,deltaZ,
               deltaX+size,deltaY+size,deltaZ
                 };
         
         for (int i = 0; i < corners.length; i++)
         {
            allCorners[i+index] = corners[i];
         }
         index += 24;
      }
      
      
      
      // 0--------->1
      // |
      // |
      // |
      // |
      // 1

        float[] textureCoordinateOnImage = new float[]{
              0,0
        };
        
        //    4---------5
        //   /|        /|
        //  / |       / |
        // 0--------->1 |
        // |  6------|--7
        // | /       | /
        // |/        |/
        // 2---------3
        
        int[] allTriangles = new int[count*72];
        index = 0;
        int a = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
           int triangles[] = new int[]{
                 a+5,0,a+4,0,a+0,0, // top
                 a+5,0,a+0,0,a+1,0, // top
                    
                 a+0,0,a+4,0,a+6,0, // left
                 a+0,0,a+6,0,a+2,0, // left
                    
                 a+1,0,a+0,0,a+2,0, // front
                 a+1,0,a+2,0,a+3,0, // front
                    
                 a+5,0,a+1,0,a+3,0, // right
                 a+5,0,a+3,0,a+7,0, // right
                    
                 a+4,0,a+5,0,a+7,0, // back
                 a+4,0,a+7,0,a+6,0, // back
                    
                 a+3,0,a+2,0,a+6,0, // bottom
                 a+3,0,a+6,0,a+7,0  // bottom
              };
           
           for (int j = 0; j < triangles.length; j++)
           {
              allTriangles[j+index] = triangles[j];
           }
           
           a += 8;
           index += 72;
        }

        this.getPoints().addAll(allCorners);
        this.getTexCoords().addAll(textureCoordinateOnImage);
        this.getFaces().addAll(allTriangles);
   }
   
   public static MeshView getSolarsystems()
   {
      MeshView cube = new MeshView(new Cubes());
      cube.setDrawMode(DrawMode.FILL);
      PhongMaterial material = new PhongMaterial();
      material.setSpecularColor(Color.ORANGE);
      cube.setMaterial(material);
      return cube;
   }
}
```

---

```java
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.PerspectiveCamera;
import javafx.scene.PointLight;
import javafx.scene.SceneAntialiasing;
import javafx.scene.SubScene;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.shape.MeshView;
import javafx.scene.transform.Rotate;
import scences.Cubes;

public class Chart3DItem extends StackPane
{
   private Group group = new Group();
   private SubScene scene3d;
   
   public Chart3DItem()
   {
      initContent();
   }

   private void initContent()
   {
      this.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
      this.getStyleClass().add("solarsystem-pane");
      this.setPrefHeight(600.0);
      this.setMinHeight(600.0);
      this.setMaxHeight(600.0);
      this.setPrefWidth(600.0);
      this.setMinWidth(600.0);
      this.setMaxWidth(600.0);
      
      this.getChildren().add(new PointLight());
      PerspectiveCamera camera = new PerspectiveCamera();
      camera.setTranslateZ(-2000);
      this.getChildren().add(camera);
      
      scene3d = new SubScene(group, 600, 600, true, SceneAntialiasing.DISABLED);
      scene3d.setCamera(camera);
      this.getChildren().add(scene3d);
   }

   public void update()
   {
      group.getChildren().clear();
      MeshView view = Cubes.getSolarsystems();
      group.getChildren().add(view);
      this.setOnMouseDragged(event -> {
         Rotate rotX = new Rotate(event.getX()/1000f);
         rotX.axisProperty().set(Rotate.X_AXIS);
         view.getTransforms().add(0,rotX);
         Rotate rotY = new Rotate(event.getY()/1000f);
         rotY.axisProperty().set(Rotate.Y_AXIS);
         view.getTransforms().add(1,rotY);
         /*Rotate rotZ = new Rotate(event.getZ()/1000f);
         rotZ.axisProperty().set(Rotate.Z_AXIS);
         view.getTransforms().add(rotZ);*/
      });
   }
}
```

[broken cube faces](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ViNme.png)

The 16 cubes, representing 15 solar systems and 1 spaceship in a 3D-grid, are added to a group, which is added to a subscene, which is added to a `StackPane` (which is added in the program as a node to a menu-item).

In the menu-item the broken cubes can be seen. Also they show up black and white, even though I choose to add Color.ORANGE to the `PhongMaterial`.

All ideas are welcome. I Googled and searched the Internet but could not find this problem of having multiple cubes in one mesh and losing color.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There was a little - minus sign, instead of a + plus sign.

```
float[] corners = new float[]{ 
           // X, Y, Z 
           deltaX,deltaY,deltaZ+size,
           deltaX+size,deltaY,deltaZ+size,
           deltaX,deltaY+size,deltaZ+size,
           deltaX+size,deltaY+size,deltaZ+size,
           deltaX,deltaY,deltaZ,
           deltaX+size,deltaY,deltaZ,
           deltaX,deltaY+size,deltaZ,
           deltaX+size,deltaY+size,deltaZ
             };
```

Now it displays correctly.

To get the orange color, the diffuseColor needs to be set.

```
 public static MeshView getSolarsystems()
 {
  MeshView cube = new MeshView(new Cubes());
  cube.setDrawMode(DrawMode.FILL);
  PhongMaterial material = new PhongMaterial();
  material.setDiffuseColor(Color.ORANGE);
  cube.setMaterial(material);
  return cube;
 }
```

I also fixed the rotation. Therefore I post the class Chart3DItem.

```
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.AmbientLight;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.PerspectiveCamera;
import javafx.scene.SceneAntialiasing;
import javafx.scene.SubScene;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.shape.MeshView;
import javafx.scene.transform.Rotate;
import scences.Cubes;

public class Chart3DItem extends StackPane
{
   private double mouseOldX, mouseOldY = 0;
   private Rotate rotateX = new Rotate(0, Rotate.X_AXIS);
   private Rotate rotateY = new Rotate(0, Rotate.Y_AXIS);
   private Rotate rotateZ = new Rotate(0, Rotate.Z_AXIS);

   private final double VIEWPORT_SIZE = 600;

   private Group group = new Group();
   private SubScene scene3d;

   public Chart3DItem()
   {
      initContent();
   }

   private void initContent()
   {
      this.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
      this.getStyleClass().add("chart3d-pane");
      this.setPrefHeight(600.0);
      this.setMinHeight(600.0);
      this.setMaxHeight(600.0);
      this.setPrefWidth(600.0);
      this.setMinWidth(600.0);
      this.setMaxWidth(600.0);
  
      this.getChildren().add(new AmbientLight());
      PerspectiveCamera camera = new PerspectiveCamera();
      camera.setTranslateZ(-300);
      this.getChildren().add(camera);
  
      scene3d = new SubScene(group, VIEWPORT_SIZE, VIEWPORT_SIZE, true, SceneAntialiasing.BALANCED);
      scene3d.setCamera(camera);
      this.getChildren().add(scene3d);
   }

   public void update()
   {
      group.getChildren().clear();
  
      MeshView view = Cubes.getSolarsystems();
      view.setTranslateX(VIEWPORT_SIZE / 2);
      view.setTranslateY(VIEWPORT_SIZE / 2);
      view.setTranslateZ(VIEWPORT_SIZE / 2);
      view.getTransforms().add(0,rotateX);
      view.getTransforms().add(1,rotateY);
      view.getTransforms().add(2,rotateZ);
      group.getChildren().add(view);
  
      rotateX.setPivotX(VIEWPORT_SIZE / 2);
      rotateX.setPivotY(VIEWPORT_SIZE / 2);
      rotateX.setPivotZ(VIEWPORT_SIZE / 2);

      rotateY.setPivotX(VIEWPORT_SIZE / 2);
      rotateY.setPivotY(VIEWPORT_SIZE / 2);
      rotateY.setPivotZ(VIEWPORT_SIZE / 2);

      rotateZ.setPivotX(VIEWPORT_SIZE / 2);
      rotateZ.setPivotY(VIEWPORT_SIZE / 2);
      rotateZ.setPivotZ(VIEWPORT_SIZE / 2);
  
      this.setOnMousePressed(event -> {
         mouseOldX = event.getSceneX();
         mouseOldY = event.getSceneY();
      });
  
      this.setOnMouseDragged(event -> {
         rotateX.setAngle(rotateX.getAngle() - (event.getSceneY() - mouseOldY));
         rotateY.setAngle(rotateY.getAngle() + (event.getSceneX() - mouseOldX));
         mouseOldX = event.getSceneX();
         mouseOldY = event.getSceneY();
      });
   }
}
```

The result so far:
[image: 16 cubes plus axis]

As you can see I added axis, which are also cubes. Therefore here the Cubes class again:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;

import business.Solarsystem;
import common.Common;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.paint.PhongMaterial;
import javafx.scene.shape.DrawMode;
import javafx.scene.shape.MeshView;
import javafx.scene.shape.TriangleMesh;
import resources.images.Images;

public class Cubes extends TriangleMesh
{   
   public Cubes ()
   {
      float size = 50;
  
      //    /Z
      //   /
      //  /
      // 0 -------->X
      // |
      // |
      // | 
      // Y
  
      //    0---------1
      //   /|        /|
      //  / |       / |
      // 4--------->5 |
      // |  2------|--3
      // | /       | /
      // |/        |/
      // 6---------7

      int count = Common.getCurrentGame().getAllSolarsystemsList().size();
  
      float[] allCorners = new float[(count+4)*24]; // +1 for spaceship cube +3 for grid cubes
      int index = 0;
  
      ArrayList<Solarsystem> systems = Common.getCurrentGame().getAllSolarsystemsList();
      Collections.sort(systems, new Comparator<business.Solarsystem>() {
         @Override
         public int compare(business.Solarsystem system1, business.Solarsystem system2)
         {
             return  system2.getName().compareTo(system1.getName());
         }
     });
  
      for (Solarsystem system : systems)
      {
         float deltaX = system.getLocation().getX().floatValue()*60; // factor is to scale the range [0 to 10} to [0 to 600]
         float deltaY = system.getLocation().getY().floatValue()*60;
         float deltaZ = system.getLocation().getZ().floatValue()*60;
     
         float[] corners = new float[]{ 
               // X, Y, Z 
               deltaX,deltaY,deltaZ+size,               // 0
               deltaX+size,deltaY,deltaZ+size,          // 1
               deltaX,deltaY+size,deltaZ+size,          // 2
               deltaX+size,deltaY+size,deltaZ+size,     // 3
               deltaX,deltaY,deltaZ,                    // 4
               deltaX+size,deltaY,deltaZ,               // 5
               deltaX,deltaY+size,deltaZ,               // 6
               deltaX+size,deltaY+size,deltaZ           // 7
                 };
     
         for (int i = 0; i < corners.length; i++)
         {
            allCorners[i+index] = corners[i];
         }
         index += 24;
      }
  
      float deltaX = Common.getCurrentGame().getCurrentSpaceship().getLocation().getX().floatValue()*60;
      float deltaY = Common.getCurrentGame().getCurrentSpaceship().getLocation().getY().floatValue()*60;
      float deltaZ = Common.getCurrentGame().getCurrentSpaceship().getLocation().getZ().floatValue()*60;
  
      float[] corners = new float[]{ 
            // X, Y, Z 
            deltaX,deltaY,deltaZ+size,               // 0
            deltaX+size,deltaY,deltaZ+size,          // 1
            deltaX,deltaY+size,deltaZ+size,          // 2
            deltaX+size,deltaY+size,deltaZ+size,     // 3
            deltaX,deltaY,deltaZ,                    // 4
            deltaX+size,deltaY,deltaZ,               // 5
            deltaX,deltaY+size,deltaZ,               // 6
            deltaX+size,deltaY+size,deltaZ           // 7
              };
  
      for (int i = 0; i < corners.length; i++)
      {
         allCorners[i+index] = corners[i];
      }
  
      index += 24;
      deltaX = 0.0f;
      deltaY = 5.0f*60;
      deltaZ = 5.0f*60;
      size = 5.0f;
  
      corners = new float[]{ 
            // X, Y, Z 
            deltaX,deltaY,deltaZ+size,               // 0
            deltaX+600f,deltaY,deltaZ+size,          // 1
            deltaX,deltaY+size,deltaZ+size,          // 2
            deltaX+600f,deltaY+size,deltaZ+size,     // 3
            deltaX,deltaY,deltaZ,                    // 4
            deltaX+600f,deltaY,deltaZ,               // 5
            deltaX,deltaY+size,deltaZ,               // 6
            deltaX+600f,deltaY+size,deltaZ           // 7
              };
  
      for (int i = 0; i < corners.length; i++)
      {
         allCorners[i+index] = corners[i];
      }
  
      index += 24;
      deltaX = 5.0f*60;
      deltaY = 0.0f;
      deltaZ = 5.0f*60;
      size = 5.0f;
  
      corners = new float[]{ 
            // X, Y, Z 
            deltaX,deltaY,deltaZ+size,               // 0
            deltaX+size,deltaY,deltaZ+size,          // 1
            deltaX,deltaY+600f,deltaZ+size,          // 2
            deltaX+size,deltaY+600f,deltaZ+size,     // 3
            deltaX,deltaY,deltaZ,                    // 4
            deltaX+size,deltaY,deltaZ,               // 5
            deltaX,deltaY+600f,deltaZ,               // 6
            deltaX+size,deltaY+600f,deltaZ           // 7
              };
  
      for (int i = 0; i < corners.length; i++)
      {
         allCorners[i+index] = corners[i];
      }
  
      index += 24;
      deltaX = 5.0f*60;
      deltaY = 5.0f*60;
      deltaZ = 0.0f;
      size = 5.0f;
  
      corners = new float[]{ 
            // X, Y, Z 
            deltaX,deltaY,deltaZ+600f,               // 0
            deltaX+size,deltaY,deltaZ+600f,          // 1
            deltaX,deltaY+size,deltaZ+600f,          // 2
            deltaX+size,deltaY+size,deltaZ+600f,     // 3
            deltaX,deltaY,deltaZ,                    // 4
            deltaX+size,deltaY,deltaZ,               // 5
            deltaX,deltaY+size,deltaZ,               // 6
            deltaX+size,deltaY+size,deltaZ           // 7
              };
  
      for (int i = 0; i < corners.length; i++)
      {
         allCorners[i+index] = corners[i];
      }
  
  
      // 0--------->1
      // |
      // |
      // |
      // |
      // 1
  
       int[][] textureNumbers = new int[][] {
            {0,1,2},
            {3,4,5},
            {6,7,8},
            {9,10,11},
        
            {12,13,14},
            {15,16,17},
        {18,19,20},
        {21,22,23},
        
        {24,25,26},
        {27,28,29},
        {30,31,32},
        {33,34,35},
        
        {36,37,38},
        {39,40,41},
        {42,43,44},
        {45,46,47},
        
        {48,49,50},
        {51,52,53},
        {54,55,56}
  };

    float[] textureCoordinateOnImage = new float[]{
          // sort backwards also
          
          0.5f,0.75f,      // 42
          0.75f,0.75f,     // 43
          0.5f,1,          // 44 => 42,43,44 light violet Zells
          
          0.25f,0.75f,     // 39
          0.5f,0.75f,      // 40
          0.25f,1,         // 41 => 39,40,41 dark violet Xoquam
          
          0,0.75f,         // 36
          0.25f,0.75f,     // 37
          0,1f,            // 38 => 36,37,38 dark brown Treblar
          
          0.75f,0.5f,      // 33
          1,0.5f,          // 34
          0.75f,0.75f,     // 35 => 33,34,35 medium brown Singuis
          
          0.5f,0.5f,       // 30
          0.75f,0.5f,      // 31
          0.5f,0.75f,      // 32 => 30,31,32 light brown Razor
          
          0.25f,0.5f,      // 27
          0.5f,0.5f,       // 28
          0.25f,0.75f,     // 29 => 27,28,29 turquoise Pot
          
          0,0.5f,          // 24
          0.25f,0.5f,      // 25
          0,0.75f,         // 26 => 24,25,26 dark blue Olam
          
          0.75f,0.25f,      // 21
          1,0.25f,          // 22
          0.75f,0.5f,       // 23 => 21,22,23 light blue Meichu
          
          0.5f,0.25f,       // 18
          0.75f,0.25f,      // 19
          0.5f,0.5f,        // 20 => 18,19,20 dark green Kantell
          
          0.25f,0.25f,      // 15
          0.5f,0.25f,       // 16
          0.25f,0.5f,       // 17 => 15,16,17 light green Irisa
          
          0,0.25f,          // 12
          0.25f,0.25f,      // 13
          0,0.5f,           // 14 => 12,13,14 dark red Holm
          
          0.75f,0,          // 9
          1,0,              // 10
          0.75f,0.25f,      // 11 => 9,10,11 pink Fantus
          
          0.5f,0,           // 6
          0.75f,0,          // 7
          0.5f,0.25f,       // 8 => 6,7,8 light red Dora
          
          0.25f,0,          // 3
          0.5f,0,           // 4
          0.25f,0.25f,      // 5 => 3,4,5 orange Bini
          
          0,0,              // 0
          0.25f,0,          // 1
          0,0.25f,          // 2 => 0,1,2 yellow Aglena
          
          0.75f,0.75f,      // 45
          1,0.75f,          // 46
          0.75f,1,          // 47 => 45,46,47 white Spaceship
          
          0.75f,0.75f,      // 48
          1,0.75f,          // 49
          0.75f,1,          // 50 => 48,49,50 white axis
          
          0.75f,0.75f,      // 51
          1,0.75f,          // 52
          0.75f,1,          // 53 => 51,52,53 white axis
          
          0.75f,0.75f,      // 54
          1,0.75f,          // 55
          0.75f,1          // 56 => 54,55,56 white axis
    };
    
    //    3---------2
    //   /|        /|
    //  / |       / |
    // 0--------->1 |
    // |  7------|--6
    // | /       | /
    // |/        |/
    // 4---------5
    
    int[] allTriangles = new int[(count+4)*72];
    index = 0;
    int a = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
       int[]t = textureNumbers[i];
       int triangles[] = new int[]{
             a+5,t[0],a+4,t[1],a+0,t[2], // top
             a+5,t[0],a+0,t[1],a+1,t[2], // top
                
             a+0,t[0],a+4,t[1],a+6,t[2], // left
             a+0,t[0],a+6,t[1],a+2,t[2], // left
                
             a+1,t[0],a+0,t[1],a+2,t[2], // front
             a+1,t[0],a+2,t[1],a+3,t[2], // front
                
             a+5,t[0],a+1,t[1],a+3,t[2], // right
             a+5,t[0],a+3,t[1],a+7,t[2], // right
                
             a+4,t[0],a+5,t[1],a+7,t[2], // back
             a+4,t[0],a+7,t[1],a+6,t[2], // back
                
             a+3,t[0],a+2,t[1],a+6,t[2], // bottom
             a+3,t[0],a+6,t[1],a+7,t[2]  // bottom
          };
       
       for (int j = 0; j < triangles.length; j++)
       {
          allTriangles[j+index] = triangles[j];
       }
       
       a += 8;
       index += 72;
    }
    
    // spaceship
    int[]t = textureNumbers[count];
    int triangles[] = new int[]{
          a+5,t[0],a+4,t[1],a+0,t[2], // top
          a+5,t[0],a+0,t[1],a+1,t[2], // top
             
          a+0,t[0],a+4,t[1],a+6,t[2], // left
          a+0,t[0],a+6,t[1],a+2,t[2], // left
             
          a+1,t[0],a+0,t[1],a+2,t[2], // front
          a+1,t[0],a+2,t[1],a+3,t[2], // front
             
          a+5,t[0],a+1,t[1],a+3,t[2], // right
          a+5,t[0],a+3,t[1],a+7,t[2], // right
             
          a+4,t[0],a+5,t[1],a+7,t[2], // back
          a+4,t[0],a+7,t[1],a+6,t[2], // back
             
          a+3,t[0],a+2,t[1],a+6,t[2], // bottom
          a+3,t[0],a+6,t[1],a+7,t[2]  // bottom
       };
    
    for (int j = 0; j < triangles.length; j++)
    {
       allTriangles[j+index] = triangles[j];
    }
    
    a += 8;
    index += 72;
    t = textureNumbers[count+1];
    // axis
    triangles = new int[]{
          a+5,t[0],a+4,t[1],a+0,t[2], // top
          a+5,t[0],a+0,t[1],a+1,t[2], // top
             
          a+0,t[0],a+4,t[1],a+6,t[2], // left
          a+0,t[0],a+6,t[1],a+2,t[2], // left
             
          a+1,t[0],a+0,t[1],a+2,t[2], // front
          a+1,t[0],a+2,t[1],a+3,t[2], // front
             
          a+5,t[0],a+1,t[1],a+3,t[2], // right
          a+5,t[0],a+3,t[1],a+7,t[2], // right
             
          a+4,t[0],a+5,t[1],a+7,t[2], // back
          a+4,t[0],a+7,t[1],a+6,t[2], // back
             
          a+3,t[0],a+2,t[1],a+6,t[2], // bottom
          a+3,t[0],a+6,t[1],a+7,t[2]  // bottom
       };
    for (int j = 0; j < triangles.length; j++)
    {
       allTriangles[j+index] = triangles[j];
    }
    
    a += 8;
    index += 72;
    t = textureNumbers[count+2];
    // axis
    triangles = new int[]{
          a+5,t[0],a+4,t[1],a+0,t[2], // top
          a+5,t[0],a+0,t[1],a+1,t[2], // top
             
          a+0,t[0],a+4,t[1],a+6,t[2], // left
          a+0,t[0],a+6,t[1],a+2,t[2], // left
             
          a+1,t[0],a+0,t[1],a+2,t[2], // front
          a+1,t[0],a+2,t[1],a+3,t[2], // front
             
          a+5,t[0],a+1,t[1],a+3,t[2], // right
          a+5,t[0],a+3,t[1],a+7,t[2], // right
             
          a+4,t[0],a+5,t[1],a+7,t[2], // back
          a+4,t[0],a+7,t[1],a+6,t[2], // back
             
          a+3,t[0],a+2,t[1],a+6,t[2], // bottom
          a+3,t[0],a+6,t[1],a+7,t[2]  // bottom
       };
    for (int j = 0; j < triangles.length; j++)
    {
       allTriangles[j+index] = triangles[j];
    }
    
    a += 8;
    index += 72;
    t = textureNumbers[count+3];
    // axis
    triangles = new int[]{
          a+5,t[0],a+4,t[1],a+0,t[2], // top
          a+5,t[0],a+0,t[1],a+1,t[2], // top
             
          a+0,t[0],a+4,t[1],a+6,t[2], // left
          a+0,t[0],a+6,t[1],a+2,t[2], // left
             
          a+1,t[0],a+0,t[1],a+2,t[2], // front
          a+1,t[0],a+2,t[1],a+3,t[2], // front
             
          a+5,t[0],a+1,t[1],a+3,t[2], // right
          a+5,t[0],a+3,t[1],a+7,t[2], // right
             
          a+4,t[0],a+5,t[1],a+7,t[2], // back
          a+4,t[0],a+7,t[1],a+6,t[2], // back
             
          a+3,t[0],a+2,t[1],a+6,t[2], // bottom
          a+3,t[0],a+6,t[1],a+7,t[2]  // bottom
       };
    for (int j = 0; j < triangles.length; j++)
    {
       allTriangles[j+index] = triangles[j];
    }
    

    this.getPoints().addAll(allCorners);
    this.getTexCoords().addAll(textureCoordinateOnImage);
    this.getFaces().addAll(allTriangles);
    
    
this.getFaceSmoothingGroups().addAll(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
          0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
          0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
          0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
          0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
          0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
          0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
          0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
          0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
          0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
          0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
          0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
          0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
          0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
          0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
          0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
          0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
          0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
          0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0);
   }

  public static MeshView getSolarsystems()
  {
     MeshView cube = new MeshView(new Cubes());
     cube.setDrawMode(DrawMode.FILL);
      PhongMaterial material = new PhongMaterial();
      material.setDiffuseMap(new Image(
        
Images.class.getResource("colors.png").toExternalForm()));
      cube.setMaterial(material);
      return cube;
   }

}
```

Comment: Since I added three more cubes as axis, now it is 19 times 12 zeros I had to add to the FaceSmoothingGroups.. Thanks to the shading idea to @Giovanni Contreras

Answer (score 3):

**Using flat shading for non-organic 3d objects .**

Flat shading is calculated from the normal of the face and , in the other hand , smooth shading is calculated from the vertices . smooth shading is recomended for organic surfaces and flat for hard edges surfaces . In javaFx  All faces are smooth by default , but we can tweak that with `getFaceSmoothingGroups()` observableList by adding 1 or 0 integers values . The length of the FaceSmoothingGroups must match with face's lenght in the mesh . 1 = smooth and 0 = flat .

In this case , a cube has 12 triangle faces  therefore  `getFaceSmoothingGroups()` must have lenght (12) . in complex shapes smooth and flat shading can be mixed as needed , but a cube has hard edges and all faces should be flat shaded .

You can read about this topic [here](https://blenderbasecamp.com/what-is-the-difference-between-smooth-shading-and-flat-shading/)

**A cube with smooth shading**

```
 getFaceSmoothingGroups().addAll(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1);
```

[image: smooth shading javafx]

**Same cube with flat shading**

```
 getFaceSmoothingGroups().addAll(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0);
```

[image: smooth shading]

A functional single class javafx app

**App.java**

```
 public class App extends Application {
        
        @Override
        public void start(Stage stage) {
            
            
            PerspectiveCamera camera = new PerspectiveCamera(true);
            camera.setTranslateZ(-8);
            MeshView meshView = new MeshView(new CubeMesh());
            meshView.setRotationAxis(Rotate.Y_AXIS);
            meshView.setRotate(30);
            meshView.setMaterial(new PhongMaterial(Color.CYAN));
            
            
            Group group3d = new Group(camera,meshView);
            Scene scene = new Scene(group3d, 640, 480, true, SceneAntialiasing.BALANCED);
            scene.setCamera(camera);
            stage.setScene(scene);
            stage.show();
        }
        
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            launch();
        }
        
        
        
        
       class CubeMesh extends TriangleMesh {

   

//  default cube size is 2x2x2  with no args constructor
    public CubeMesh() {

        initialize();
        setDefaultPoints();
    }

    

    // by default this mesh has 2x2x2 units length
    private void setDefaultPoints() {

        // 24 length each vertex has 3 numbers (x,y,z), therefore  a cube needs 3*8 = 24 
        getPoints().addAll(
                -1, 1, -1, //v0 front bottom left
                1, 1, -1, //v1  front bottom right
                -1, -1, -1,//v2 front to left
                1, -1, -1, //v3  front top right
                -1, 1, 1, //v4   back bottom left  
                1, 1, 1, //v5     back bottom right 
                - 1, -1, 1, //v6  back top left 
                1, -1, 1 // v7   back top right 

        );

    }
    
    

    private void initialize() {

        // all uv are pointing to 0,0 coords
        getTexCoords().addAll(0, 0);

        // each face needs 6 values and and a cube is made of 12 triangle faces (6*12= 72)
        getFaces().addAll(
                // front faces  
                0, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0, // f1
                1, 0, 3, 0, 2, 0, // f2

                // right faces 
                1, 0, 5, 0, 3, 0, // f3
                5, 0, 7, 0, 3, 0, // f4

                // back faces 

                5, 0, 4, 0, 7, 0, // f5
                4, 0, 6, 0, 7, 0, //f6

                // left faces 

                0, 0, 6, 0, 4, 0, // f7
                0, 0, 2, 0, 6, 0, // f8

                // top faces

                2, 0, 3, 0, 7, 0, // f9
                2, 0, 7, 0, 6, 0, // f10

                // bottom faces 

                0, 0, 5, 0, 1, 0, // f11
                4, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0 // f12    

        );
        // flat shading
        
        getFaceSmoothingGroups().addAll(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0);

    }

    
}

}
```

Comment: Thank you, I needed to add 16 * 12  times the value 1 for the FaceSmoothingGroups, because I have got 16 cubes in the mesh. Now it looks great!